# How to run valgrind with basic c example?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

Installation:

```
bzip2 -d valgrind-3.10.1.tar.bz2
tar -xf valgrind-3.10.1.tar
```

then:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

or simplier

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

How to run valgrind on that simple program example1.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *x = malloc(100); /* or, in C++, "char *x = new char[100] */
    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes example1
valgrind: example1: command not found
```

Output from console:

```
valgrind: example1: command not found
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks good. You only need to add a `./` before your executable. Without it, `valgrind` fails to find it and reports `'command not found'`.

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./example1
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 4):

First, compile your C program (-g is extremely important; without debug info in the executable valgrind cannot tell you line numbers from the source code where the violations occur nor the original line of the allocations of the memory being violated.):

```
gcc -g example1.c -o example1
```

Then run valgrind on the executable:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./example1
```